# Twitter API 1.1 search/tweets - search by date

Tags: twitter

Since the "since" param is no longer in use, how can I search tweets older than specific date ? I understand how to use [since_id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets), but in my case I don't have any historic tweet to take the tweet_id from. How is search by date done these days ?

Comment: Hi Bobby_D, I am also trying to do the same thing. Did you find any way to search tweets between 2 different dates using Twitter Search Api?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but since it has no answer i share what i have found regarding this question by reading the docs and using the API.

`Since` and `until` params are only for maximum 9 past days.

Instead we can use `since_id` and `max_id`. You have to set them to unique ids of tweets. You can find one tweet in the specified time (from any user you want). Detect the id by using the API or simply by Developer tools of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `until` param:

> Returns tweets generated before the given date. Date should be
>   formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Keep in mind that the search index may not go
>   back as far as the date you specify here.